# How do I iterate and print hashtable in c?

Tags: c, hashtable

The implementation uses a structure similar to the "Static Sequence List" (it uses an array to store the elements). I can insert and query 1 item. But I need to list all the items.

The code:

```
struct cidade {
    int pkCidade;
    char nomeCidade[50];
};

struct hashCidade {
    int qtdCidade, TABLE_SIZE;
    struct cidade **itensCidade;
};

typedef struct hashCidade HashCidade;

HashCidade *createHashCidade(int TABLE_SIZE);
void releaseHashCidade(HashCidade *ha);
int insertHashCidade(HashCidade *ha, struct cidade CidadeH);
int findHashCidade(HashCidade *ha, char *str, struct cidade *CidadeH);

HashCidade *createHashCidade(int TABLE_SIZE) {
    HashCidade *ha = (HashCidade*)malloc(sizeof(HashCidade));
    if (ha != NULL) {
        int i;
        ha->TABLE_SIZE = TABLE_SIZE;
        ha->itensCidade = (struct cidade **)
                                malloc(TABLE_SIZE * sizeof(struct cidade*));
        if (ha->itensCidade == NULL) {
            free(ha);
            return NULL;
        }
        ha->qtdCidade = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < ha->TABLE_SIZE; i++)
            ha->itensCidade[i] = NULL;
    }
    return ha;
}

void releaseHashCidade(HashCidade *ha) {
    if (ha != NULL) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < ha->TABLE_SIZE; i++) {
            if (ha->itensCidade[i] != NULL)
                free(ha->itensCidade[i]);
        }
        free(ha->itensCidade);
        free(ha);
    }
}

int insertHashCidade(HashCidade *ha, struct cidade CidadeH) {
    if (ha == NULL || ha->qtdCidade == ha->TABLE_SIZE)
        return 0;
    int chave = valorString(CidadeH.nomeCidade);
    int pos = chaveDivisao(chave, ha->TABLE_SIZE);
    struct cidade *nova;
    nova = (struct cidade *)malloc(sizeof(struct cidade));
    if(nova == NULL)
        return 0;
    *nova = CidadeH;
    ha->itensCidade[pos] = nova;
    ha->qtdCidade++;
    return 1;
}

int findHashCidade(HashCidade *ha, char *str, struct cidade *CidadeH) {
    if (ha == NULL)
        return 'n';
    int chave = valorString(str);
    int pos = chaveDivisao(chave, ha->TABLE_SIZE);
    if (ha->itensCidade[pos] == NULL)
        return 0;
    else
        *CidadeH = *(ha->itensCidade[pos]);
    return 1;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You'll have to allocate a `struct cidade`, initialize it, and assign a pointer to it at the appropiate place. Oh,  and for printing: walk the array, and for each entry: walk the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you can just iterate over the non `NULL` pointers in the hash array and print the corresponding structure details:

```
void printCidade(const struct cidade *cp) {
    printf("%s\n", cp->nomeCidade);
}

void printHashCidade(const HashCidade *ha) {
    if (ha != NULL) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < ha->TABLE_SIZE; i++) {
            if (ha->itensCidade[i] != NULL)
                printCidade(ha->itensCidade[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AdalbertoJoséBrasaca: glad to help. Upvoting the answer is a standard way to say thank you on stackoverflow :)